# Error while accessing mirror api using php sdk

Tags: google-mirror-api

i am using the php sdk  for mirror api I have completed the authentication proceess by when get the timeline card exception error throughs

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline?maxResults=3&key=-DBblCsty21sfV9MTpZoKNvxsss: (403) Access Not Configured' in /var/www/glass/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66 
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/glass/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 /var/www/glass/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#2 /var/www/glass/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_MirrorService.php(434): Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array)
#3 /var/www/glass/index.php(137): google_TimelineServiceResource->listTimeline(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/glass/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, it sounds like you haven't enabled the Mirror API in the code console for this project.

1. Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and select the project you're working on.
2. Select the `Services` menu item on the left.
3. Scroll down to the `Google Mirror API` and make sure it is turned on.

If you do not have this API available, it means you haven't been whitelisted for it. If you're a Glass Explorer, contact a Glass Guide using the 800 number or the email address for support and ask to be permitted. If you are not a Glass Explorer, the API isn't available to you at this time unless a Glass Explorer permits you access to one of their projects.

Comment: Hi prisoner thanks for your reply ,i am from india and i think glass has not been introduced here.if i buy glass will it work here and will they include me in Glass Explorer

Comment: Glass is currently only available to people living in the US to a limited number of people who have previously signed up to be part of the Explorer program. There are regulatory issues with its availability in other parts of the world.

Comment: :-( just curious to learn any way thanks for your reply hope they will introduce in other part of the world sooooon

Comment: sorry one more doubt is there any group that i can follow to know the activity of the mirror api

Answer (score 1):

Google APIs have been known to misbehave when you provide both OAuth2 credentials and an API Key. Also since you have to use OAuth2 to access the Mirror API, the key=xxxxx isn't necessary anyway.

If you are using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP you can simply remove the following line from your code:

```
 $client->setDeveloperKey($key);
```

Not entirely sure if this causes your issue, but I have come across similar issues in other Google APIs.